# A Query In the String

Tags: php, syntax-error, http-status-code-500

I didn't know what to write about the title of the problem:) 
I want to add a string to the query but I get internal 500 error

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$name = "Peter";
echo $arr[$name];  // Output: 65
```

It's correct but,

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->$name;
```

not working.

Of course this is not normal code but caybe this could be a method?

Comment: A 500 error means that there's an internal server error. Check your servers error log (or turn display_errors on) to see what the actual error message is. Have you even defined `$name` in the second code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your first code is correct. Your second code isn't. So don't use the second code.

Comment: it works in my computer

Comment: @Quentin I know. But I need this method.

Comment: What is the error in the log?

Comment: "_I want to add a string to the query_" What query?

Answer (score 0):

Given a json string `{"name":"foo"}`
You can display name by writing

```
$json = '{"name":"foo"}';
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->name ;
```

Since name is a property of object $data .

if you'd write $data->$name , it would mean you have a $name variable somewhere you wanted to refer.